# Is it OK to go from Hashed to Encrypted password type in an ASP.NET membership provider?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication, membership-provider

I've have an asp.net web app, forms authentication, that's uses Hashed password type. 
Will I run across any problems if I change the password type to Encrypted?

I see that, if I change to Encrypted, attempted password recovery for old hashed passwords fails gracefully, which is good. Are there any not so good things that might show up if I change.

If someone changes their password after I make the change to Encrypted the password type stays as Hashed. Is there any way to force it to store the new password as Encrypted instead?

Answer (score 2):

> if I change the password type to Encrypted?

Why?

Hashed is safer (password recovery: generate a new password and send that).

The only reason I can see to use encrypted is if the passwords are needed by the system itself (e.g. to authenticate to another system as the user).

Comment: The system does not to be rock solid secure. I want the users to be able to retrieve their password.
Having the extra step of reseting a password, logging in and changing the password back to something memerable may be one step too many between trying to buy something and buying something.

Comment: I suppose it really depends very much on how often users have forgotten their passwords.

Comment: Whenever I hear that a system does not need to be all that secure, I immediately suspect security theatre... which may be an accurate description of most web shops, now that I think about it.

Comment: @Pontus: indeed... and the way people tend to reuse passwords means many a site is competing to be the weakest link.